# creating alias for a bash script with a wild card option in the argument

Tags: bash, shell

I wanted to create the `alias` for the a bash script that make use of wild card as an argument. When I am trying to make use of the `alias` cmd its not giving the required output.

The usage of the alias cmd will be `log_list /tmp/abc*`

```
   #usage log_list /tmp/abc*
   alias log_list=`sh scriptname $1`

   #here is the script code
   for file_name in $* ; do
      if [ ! -d $file_name ] && [ -f $file_name ] ; then

          #do some processing ...
          echo $file_name
      fi
   done
```

Comment: Single quotes not backticks on the alias definition. You are running the command there. Look at the output of `alias log_list`.

Comment: BTW, `[ -f "$file_name" ]` should never return true for anything where `[ -d "$file_name" ]` returns true, so I'm not sure why you have the former check as well instead of leaning only on the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases don't handle arguments via `$1` and the like; they just prepend their text directly to the rest of the command line.

Either use:

```
alias log_list='sh scriptname'     # note that these are single-quotes, not backticks
```

...or a function:

```
log_list() { sh scriptname "$@"; }
```

...though if your script is named `log_list`, marked executable, and located somewhere in the PATH, that alias or function should be completely unnecessary.

---

Now, that said, your proposed implementation of `log_list` also has a bunch of bugs. A cleaned-up version might look more like...

```
#!/bin/sh
for file_name in "$@" ; do
   if [ ! -d "$file_name" ] && [ -f "$file_name" ] ; then
       #do some processing ...
       printf '%s\n' "$file_name"
   fi
done
```